# Adding box shadow to TextInputField flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working on a project involving inputs. I want a box-shadow to an input. I have tried the BoxShadow widget on the container but it drops the shadow on the content of that not the outside of it.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap textField with Container and give boxShadow

```
Container(
      decoration:  BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, blurRadius: 2.0, spreadRadius: 0.4)
          ]),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            isDense: true,
            counterText: "",
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius:
                new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide.none)),
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        maxLines: 1,
        maxLength: 20,
        // controller: _locationNameTextController,
      )
  );
```

Comment: This does not take account of the input label.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [control_style](https://pub.dev/packages/control_style) package. Just wrap `border` value of `InputDecoration` with `DecoratedInputBorder` and configure shadow in `shadow` parameter. The `shadow` configuration you can just copy from `boxShadow` decoration of your `Container`.

```dart
    TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: DecoratedInputBorder(
        child: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        shadow: const [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.blue,
            blurRadius: 12,
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
```

The result should looks this way:

[image]